# Rails 3. Get most recent update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an API using Rails 3. A user can have several contact items, like phones, emails, websites and address. Each item got its own model.

I need to do caching in my iPhone app that is using this API therefore I need to get the date when the latest update to any of the items occured and match it against the timestamp of the cache file.

How can I get the most updated items (when comparing all the item tables)?

I am getting the most recent item for each item table like this. Is this really good?

```
@phones = @user.phones.order("updated_at desc").limit(1)
```

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make use of ActiveRecord's `touch` method. This is especially useful if you have one parent record with many child records. Every time the child records are saved or destroyed the parent record will have it's `updated_at` field set to the current time.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :phones
  has_many :addresses
end

class Phone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, touch: true
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, touch: true
end
```

Now any time an address or a phone is updated, the User's `updated_at` will be set to the current time.

To check when the last updated for the current user took place, over all their tables, you now do:

```
@last_updated = @user.updated_at
```

For a small overhead in writes you gain a lot with simpler queries on checking your cache expiry. The documentation for this can be found under [belongs_to options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to).

Comment: This is so cool! I had no idea that this existed. You saved my day Douglas. Thank you so much!